# Seeking data for global base map?

Tags: data, imagery, landsat, sentinel-2, global

I'm part of a group making global visualization software. I need to find earth imagery (visual range and hopefully IR as well) between 500 m/pixel and 75 m/pixel.

The blue marble next generation data doesn't get high enough resolution.

There seem to be some pay services for this like Planet Observer, TruEarth , and Digital Globe. I'd like to avoid paying if I could.

I see that there is Sentinel 2 data which I think might meet my needs but I'm having trouble finding how to download it. Even on the ESO website I can't find a  good way to do it en masse (or at least more than one image at a time.

In the end I need the data tiled so that my project can zoom. I could probably do that myself if the data is an a reasonable form to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning Sentinel-2A: there is no global cloud-free coverage available yet.

For example, there is a Landsat global mosaik available:

- https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/Tri-Decadal_Pan_Mosaics

Citation: "The collections are derived from approximately 7,461 TM (Landsat 4-5) images and approximately 8,500 ETM+ (Landsat 7) images, which were selected to provide a full set of global coverage (circa 1990 and circa 2000). All selected images are either cloud-free or contain minimal cloud cover."

There are also some providers offering this coverage as Web Service (WMS).

Answer (score 0):

Concerning mass download I suggest you use Amazon Open Public Dataset
http://sentinel-pds.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
You will get fastest access by using AWS EC2 machines although you can download the data over HTTP as well. However, note that there about 1.5 trillion pixels covering the surface of the Earth so you will need to download and process pretty large volume of data.

You might want to try accessing Sentinel Hub WMS (http://sentinel-hub.com/apps/wms), however note that service is payable.
Disclosure: I am working at Sinergise, which is developing this service.

Comment: If you are promoting a Sinergise product you should disclose your [affiliation with that company](http://www.sinergise.com/en/contact).